# jQuery mouseout behavior issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very odd problem using mouseenter and mouseout on a div. If I hover the text in my div coming from above or below, everything works fine. The "toggle" text `<p style="padding-left: 30px;">text</p>` will show and when I remove the mouse, the text disappears.

**But** if I hover the div coming from the left or right side, the mouseout event triggers instantly and the text disappears again.

I didn't delete the CSS because some of that might cause the problem? Help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#fuss_hover").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      jQuery("#fuss_ak").fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
  jQuery("#fuss_hover").on({
    mouseout: function() {
      jQuery("#fuss_ak").fadeOut(500);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fuss_hover" style="margin: 6px 0px 6px 90px; width: 48%;"><span style="font-family: 'book antiqua',palatino; font-size: 14pt;">*</span><span style="font-family: 'book antiqua',palatino; font-size: 14pt; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help;">Mouseover Text</span>
</div>
<div id="fuss_ak" style="display: none; margin: 8px 0px 8px 90px; width: 75%;">
  <p style="padding-left: 30px;">text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed your code to snippet (working example) and I'm not sure what exactly is the problem. Please double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseout` fires as soon as *any* other element than the target is hovered - and that includes child elements.

The proper counterpart to `mouseenter` is `mouseleave`, not `mouseout`.

Comment: With mouseleave everything works as intented, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a combination of your use of `mouseout` and the fact that you don't `stop()` successive events from adding new animations on the queue.

To fix this use `mouseleave` and call `stop(true)` before `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`. You can also then simplify the code to simply use `hover()` (as it uses both the previously mentioned events) and use `fadeToggle()`.

I'd also strongly suggest you use an external stylesheet over inline CSS. Try this:

```js
$("#fuss_hover").hover(function() {
  $("#fuss_ak").stop(true).fadeToggle(500);
});
```

```css
#fuss_hover {
  margin: 6px 0px 6px 90px;
  width: 48%;
  font-family: 'book antiqua', palatino;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
#fuss_hover .text {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  cursor: help;
}
#fuss_ak {
  display: none;
  margin: 8px 0px 8px 90px;
  width: 75%;
}
#fuss_ak p {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fuss_hover">
  <span>*</span>
  <span class="text">Mouseover Text</span>
</div>
<div id="fuss_ak">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works as well as CBroes, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

you can use delay() when you are triggering mouse out.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#fuss_hover").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                jQuery("#fuss_ak").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
        jQuery("#fuss_hover").on({
            mouseout: function() {
                jQuery("#fuss_ak").delay(500).fadeOut(100);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fuss_hover" style="margin: 6px 0px 6px 90px; width: 48%;"><span style="font-family: 'book antiqua',palatino; font-size: 14pt;">*</span><span style="font-family: 'book antiqua',palatino; font-size: 14pt; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help;">Mouseover Text</span>
</div>
<div id="fuss_ak" style="display: none; margin: 8px 0px 8px 90px; width: 75%;">
    <p style="padding-left: 30px;">text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#fuss_hover").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      jQuery("#fuss_ak").fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
  jQuery("#fuss_hover").on({
    mouseout: function() {
      jQuery("#fuss_ak").fadeOut(500);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fuss_hover" style="font-family: 'book antiqua',palatino; font-size: 14pt;padding: 6px 0px 6px 90px; width: 100%;">*Mouseover Text 
</div>
<div id="fuss_ak" style="display: none; margin: 8px 0px 8px 90px; width: 75%;">
  <p style="padding-left: 30px;">text</p>
</div>
```